# Using include inside a function PHP

Tags: php, file, function, include

My problem is I need to execute a function every time I include a file.

But I know that if I use include inside a function, it will mess up.

So there is a way to change include function to execute a function inside? Or to create a "listener" that gets triggered if I use include?

Example:

```
function include_file($path){

    if($this->error)
         echo $this->error_msg;

    include_once($path);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. But why do you need that?

Comment: Because I have a controller that include several files.
But I don't want to execute a function that verify if there is an error and another one to include.

Comment: are you using framework ?

Comment: Only joomla, if you count as a framework

Comment: @Maurício Giordano: your explanation doesn't look like a good reason to do so anyway

Comment: But is there a way to trigger an action when using include() ?

Answer (score 0):

> But I know that if I use include inside a function, it will mess up.

IMHO, it won't mess up.

**including_file.php**

```
<?php

include_once ("included_file.php");
echo $test;
?>
```

**included_file.php**

```
<?php

function myFunction()
{
return "Testing 123";
}

$test=myFunction();

?>
```

This will call myFunction everytime this file is included. This sounds very trivial unless i misunderstood the question

Comment: That would be completely unecessary... I would have to put the function into every file.

Comment: Nopes you wont have to. Includes do not work like every include works on its own members only. If you call a function in any of the included files that has already been defined in any of them, it will work.

Comment: That is not what I meant... I have several files to include, but I never include more than one at a time.

Comment: Yes but i think the question needs to put up a scenario here as to what it expects in output. Only then can one put up a related example